only one of the 2 diy installed pendants lights in a new build are working
been in a new build for 2 years. Kitchen also had 2 pendants ligths that had been covered with a white plastic cap.
I finally bought two pendants lights to install. one is working (left one), while the one on the right is not working. I even tried to swap the pendant lightsm just in case one of the newly bought light fixtures is defective, however, it still is only is the one on the left working.
a few things I observed which I don't know, if it may be the issue and need your help with:

The wiring of the working pendant light on the left in the ceiling had two white cables, each having one black, white and brown wires. I tried connected first to one of the set of cables (black, white and brown wires from the same electric cable)it did not work. I then tried with the other cable connecting its black, white and brown wires to the pendant lights and it worked!
-However, the one on the right only had one cable with black, white and brown wires, which is typical to videos I have seen on youtube. When I initially open the plastic cap for the one on the right and only saw one set cable with black, white and brown wires, I was happy thought it would be easy. However, this pendant light on the right is even the one now NOT WORKING. I tried switching pendant lights and still the one on the right is not working. The cables do appear very normal.

Any help figuring out the issue will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

By brown, do you mean a bare wire.  White cable with white, black and maybe brown/bare is common NM-B cable  The brown/bare wire is ground and can only connect to a another bare or green wire or to a metal box.  With the breaker off, check the wires connected to the switch and edit your question with pictures or description.  White and black wires on the switch need different wiring to lights.

Some photographs would be extremely helpful and reduce the use of abstractions.

The light box on the left needs to have each black, white and brown wire connected together and the wires from the pendant light fixture tied to each black, whit and brown.  Then there will be power to the left light as well as  transferred to the light on the right.
Be safe and work with the power off. Use the proper wire nuts on each splice.

In the receptacle box that has two conductors, you should have pig-tailing from the neutral (white) wire and the hot (black wire) going to the white and black wires (or screws depending on the design) on the pendant receptacle respectively.
One light fixture should not be continuing the circuit to the next light fixture in a manner that is passing power through the light bulb to the next fixture.
There should be a connection of the two white conductors to each other and then two black conductors to each other with each having a branched off wire going to the first light fixture first.
In the fixture that only has the one conductor, they should each terminate on the light fixture's wiring and then light fixture itself will close the circuit.
The third "brown" wire is probably just bare copper metal.  That is the ground wire which should connect to the first pendant (the one with two conductors) and it should also continue to the pendant light with the one conductor.
Check the white and black wires for continuity between the junction boxes.
If this test does not show continuity, then there must be a break in the wire and the conductor has to be replaced.  If there is continuity, then it is a wiring issue.
I suppose there is also a huge assumption that those two junction boxes are wired together in the first place.  It would be odd, but could it be possible that the single conductor comes off of a different switch altogether?

I'm guessing that the guys who installed your lights messed up. If you want to be confident, you must run a few tests. First, out the wire, you're guessing, is the jumper. You will isolate the jumper in the left pendant and wire nut the white and black wires together. Then, on the right side, you'll touch the meter to each side of the wire... if it beeps, congrats. All that's wrong is the way you've hooked it up. If it doesn't, that means the wire is cut or it's the wrong wire. If it's cut, run a new one; if it's the wrong wire, take the box down and fish around for the right one.
